# Jquery валидатор не работает

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, валидация

Добавляю самый простой Jquery validator, но он не работает.

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}resources/bower_components/bootstrap/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}resources/bower_components/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}resources/external/additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="form-wrapper" class="form-wrapper">
            <div id="add-form-${parameter.selectedTypeHistory}" class="add-form">
                <spring-form:form id="add-government-form" modelAttribute="governmentWrapper" action="/addGovernment" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                    <spring-form:hidden path="type" value="${parameter.selectedTypeHistory}"/>

                    <spring-form:hidden path="${governmentType}.type" value="${parameter.selectedTypeHistory}"/>
                    <spring-form:hidden path="${governmentType}.id" id="edit-action-val"/>
                    <spring-form:hidden path="action" value="Add" id="action-val"/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <spring-form:input id="name" name="name" path="${governmentType}.name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
                            <spring-form:errors path="${governmentType}.name" cssClass="error-message"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="cemp">Employee Count</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <spring-form:input id="cemp" name="cemp" path="${governmentType}.countOfEmployees" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Count of Employees"/>
                            <spring-form:errors path="${governmentType}.countOfEmployees" cssClass="error-message"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${parameter.selectedTypeHistory eq 'CARS'}">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="filials">Filials</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <spring-form:input id="filials" name="filials" path="${governmentType}.rawOpenedFilials" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Opened Filials"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="models">Best Models</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <spring-form:input id="models" name="models" path="${governmentType}.rawProducedModels" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enabled Models"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="add-bank-datepicker">Date</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <spring-form:input id="add-bank-datepicker" name="datepicker" path="${governmentType}.dateOfBase" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Birthday Date"/>
                                    <spring-form:errors path="${governmentType}.dateOfBase" cssClass="error-message"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="hm">Bosses</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <spring-form:input id="hm" name="hm" path="${governmentType}.headMens" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Bosses names"/>
                                    <spring-form:errors path="${governmentType}.headMens" cssClass="error-message"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                        <spring-form:button type="submit" name="submit-butt" disabled="false" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Save</spring-form:button>
                    </div>
                </spring-form:form>
            </div>
        <div/>
```

**И валидатор**

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#add-government-form').validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true
                },
                cemp: {
                    required: true
                },
                filials: {
                    required: true
                },
                models: {
                    required: true
                },
                datepicker: {
                    required: true
                },
                hm: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "This field must not be empty"
                },
                cemp: {
                    required: "This field must not be empty"
                },
                filials: {
                    required: "This field must not be empty"
                },
                models: {
                    required: "This field must not be empty"
                },
                datepicker: {
                    required: "This field must not be empty"
                },
                hm: {
                    required: "This field must not be empty"
                }
            }
```

Please, help me, буду очень признателен.

Comment: Думаю, вам бы быстрее ответили, если бы вы предоставили скомпилированный HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После компиляции и отображению на странице  `<spring-form` изменяет поставленный атрибут `"name"` на другой, а именно значение которое находится в `"path"`, после изменения филдов для валидации в объявлении валидатора все заработало.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#add-government-form').validate({
            rules: {
                '${governmentType}.name': {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 12
                },
                '${governmentType}.countOfEmployees': {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 2
                },
                '${governmentType}.rawOpenedFilials': {
                    required: true
                },
                '${governmentType}.rawProducedModels': {
                    required: true
                },
                '${governmentType}.dateOfBase': {
                    required: true
                },
                '${governmentType}.headMens': {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 25
                }
            },
            /*TODO move to message.properties*/
            messages: {
                '${governmentType}.name': {
                    required: "This field must not be empty",
                    minlength: "Username length must be more then 3 and less then 12 symbols",
                    maxlength: "Username length must be more then 3 and less then 12 symbols"
                },
                '${governmentType}.countOfEmployees': {
                    required: "This field must not be empty",
                    maxlength: "Max count must not be bigger then 100 employees"
                },
                '${governmentType}.rawOpenedFilials': {
                    required: "This field must not be empty"
                },
                '${governmentType}.rawProducedModels': {
                    required: "This field must not be empty"
                },
                '${governmentType}.dateOfBase': {
                    required: "This field must not be empty"
                },
                '${governmentType}.headMens': {
                    required: "This field must not be empty",
                    minlength: "Length must be more then 3 and less then 25 symbols",
                    maxlength: "Length must be more then 3 and less then 25 symbols"
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });
```